# Ajax can't get complete Json data in Spring MVC use fastjson parsed jsonstring as response

Tags: java, json, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
role
@Entity
public class Role {
 private int id;
 private String name;
 private String state;
 private Set<Users> users;
 private Set<Menu> menus;
 @Id
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@Column(length=50)
public String getName(){
return name;
}
@Column(length=6)
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
@OneToMany(mappedBy="role",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Users> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
menu
@Entity
public class Menu {
private int id;
private String name;
private String parentName;
private String url;
private String state;
private Set<Role> roles;
@Id
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
@Column(length=50)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
@Column(length=50)
public String getParentName() {
    return parentName;
}
@Column(length=100)
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="menus",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
@Column(length=6)
public String getState() {
    return state;
}

output json
[{"id":7,"menus":[{"id":8,"name":"需求分析管理","parentName":"项目管理","roles":[{"id":2,"menus":[{"id":2,"name":"任务管理","parentName":"0","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"id":1,"menus":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0]"},{"id":1,"name":"项目管理","parentName":"0","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"}, {"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":17,"name":"发件箱","parentName":"信息箱","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"id":5,"menus":[{"id":15,"name":"发信息","parentName":"信息箱","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"id":4,"menus":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0]"},{"id":22,"name":"信息查看","parentName":"我的信息","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].  menus[0].roles[1]"},{"id":3,"menus":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2]"},{"id":3,"name":"信息箱","parentName":"0","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":4,"name":"客户信息管理","parentName":"0","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":18,"name":"客户信息","parentName":"客户信息管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1]"},{"id":12,"name":"创建任务","parentName":"任务管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":6,"name":"我的信息","parentName":"0","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":14,"name":"我的任务","parentName":"任务管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":13,"name":"任务信息","parentName":"任务管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":23,"name":"修改密码","parentName":"我的信息","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":16,"name":"收件箱","parentName":"信息箱","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"}],"name":"普通程序员","state":"启用","users":[{"age":34,"duty":"初级工程师","hiredate":1475942400000,"id":152,"mobileno":"13526783355","name":"王五","role":{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"},"sex":"男","state":"正常"}]}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[8]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[3]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[11]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[12]"}],"name":"打水工","state":"禁用","users":[]},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[8]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2]"},{"id":5,"name":"权限管理","parentName":"0","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[11]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[12]"}],"name":"扫地工","state":"禁用","users":[]},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":19,"name":"人员管理","parentName":"权限管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"}],"state":"启用","url":"userAction_query"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[2]"},{"id":10,"name":"功能管理","parentName":"项目管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0]"}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[4]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[3]"},{"id":11,"name":"附件管理","parentName":"项目管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"}],"state":"启用"},{"id":9,"name":"模块管理","parentName":"项目管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0]"}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1]"},{"id":21,"name":"菜单资源管理","parentName":"权限管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"}],"state":"启用","url":"menuAction_resounce"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[7]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[8]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[4]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[9]"},{"id":20,"name":"角色管理","parentName":"权限管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"}],"state":"启用","url":"roleAction_query"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[10]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[11]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[12]"},{"id":7,"name":"基本信息管理","parentName":"项目管理","roles":[{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0]"}],"state":"启用"}],"name":"管理员","state":"启用","users":[{"age":34,"duty":"管理员","hiredate":1475942400000,"id":150,"mobileno":"13526783366","name":"张三","role":{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},"sex":"男","state":"正常"}]},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[5]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[4]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[3]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[8]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[9]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[7]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[8]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[9]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[10]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[11]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4].menus[12]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[22]"}],"name":"项目经理","state":"启用","users":[{"age":34,"duty":"项目经理","hiredate":1475942400000,"id":151,"mobileno":"13526783344","name":"李四","role":{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},"sex":"男","state":"正常"}]},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0]"}],"state":"启用"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[5]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[22]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[9]"}],"name":"总经理","state":"禁用","users":[]},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0]"},{"$ref":"$[0].menus[0].roles[0].menus[0].roles[1].menus[2].roles[1].menus[0].roles[2].menus[1].roles[4]"}]
```

this is the code I use to get this json data:

```
$.post("roleAction_findForAjax",{},function(role){
            for(var i=0;i<role.length;i++){
                alert(role[i].id+","+role[i].name);
                $("#roleid").append("<option value="+role[i].id+">"+role[i].name+"</option>");
                }
        },"text");
```

but I only get the first `role` the others are undefined. This is the js console log :
[image]

this is the controller code

```
@RequestMapping("/roleAction_findForAjax")
public void findForAjax(HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception{ 
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    QueryResult<Role> role=superService.getScrollData(Role.class);
    for(Role roles:role.getResultlist()){
        System.out.println(roles.getId()+"\t"+roles.getName());         
    }
    String json=JSONArray.toJSONString(role.getResultlist());
    System.out.println(json+"----------------------------------------------------------------");
    resp.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

I test the json in http://www.bejson.com/:
[image]

Comment: Please share controller code

Comment: I print the right json data in java console, but I can not get right data in ajax

Comment: is this like woking fine System.out.println(json+"----------------------------------------------------------------");

Comment: the print json is in the first line

Comment: Please share output of line System.out.println(json);

Comment: It's above the **this is the code I use to get this json data:**

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("roleAction_findForAjax",{},function(data){
            for(var i=0;i<role.length;i++){
                alert(role[i].id+","+role[i].name);
                $("#roleid").append("<option value="+role[i].id+">"+role[i].name+"</option>");
                }
        },"text");
```

Change code role.length to data.length:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
```

Or

```
 },"text");
```

To:

```
},'json');
```

Comment: the output is use acturally use data.length....and change the return type to json get the same data~

Comment: whats the length is comming??

Comment: the result is six

Comment: How much time alert is comming ??

Comment: six time . first one is right **7,总经理**,the other is undifined,undifined

Comment: @ZahiZou I think your json is not like that you are trying to access Please see json carefully or share Role Class

Comment: I use json validator to test the output json, then show it is valid json.

Comment: Please Access valid filed according  to your json, you are accessing invalid

Comment: @ZahiZou ya its valid json but you are not accessing it according to its architecture Please access all array from it in java it self then you realize proper format

Comment: @ZahiZou Please see menus is a array and it has id and name so you have to understand first what you want ot access

Comment: Thanks very much for answering me so patient, If I change the id or name in menu.java or role.java, there are so many class I need to change .  May be I can solve it tomorrow. Thanks again !